# Flutter build failed in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I have a flutter apps which is building perfectly in another machine(ubuntu 18.04). Now I am using ubuntu 19.10 , when I tried to run this apps using flutter run command, its throws these errors:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Primo EF6 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Cannot create service of type PayloadSerializer using ToolingBuildSessionScopeServices.createPayloadSerializer() as there is a problem with parameter #2 of type PayloadClassLoaderFactory.
> Cannot create service of type PayloadClassLoaderFactory using ToolingBuildSessionScopeServices.createClassLoaderFactory() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type CachedClasspathTransformer.

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 4s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         5.5s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I think it is gradle issue. I am using flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this problem. There was a permission issue on .gradle directory, it was readonly . So changing permission solves this issue.